# How to place an iframe over another iframe of same width and height using HTML

Tags: html, iframe, href

I am trying to run the following code so that whenever I click on a link, the respective page gets displayed in the iframe. I am trying to overlay `iframes`, but the code doesn't seem to work as expected.

```html
<iframe name="IFrame1" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;   display: block;position: relative;" src="https://www.link1.com"></iframe>

<iframe name="IFrame2" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; top: 10px;left: 10px;display:block;position: absolute;" src="http://www.link2.com"></iframe>


<p><a href="https://www.link1.com" target="IFrame1">link1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.link2.com" target="IFrame2">link2</a></p>
```

Kindly help me get over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use single `iframe` only.

```html
<iframe name="IFrame1" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;   display: block; 
position: relative;" src="https://www.link1.com">
</iframe>


<p><a href="https://www.link1.com" target="IFrame1">link1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://example.com/" target="IFrame1">link2</a></p>
```

Comment: <iframe name="IFrame1" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;   display: block; 
position: relative;" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>


<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="IFrame1">link1</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.quora.com/" target="IFrame1">link2</a></p>

Comment: Make sure the links are valid.

Comment: The links are valid, still, the problem exists! And I am not able to figure out what's wrong!!

Comment: hey, tell me one thing, what's the valid link for quora? https://www.quora.com?? I tried this very link only.

Comment: If you open console you'll see an error `https://www.quora.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.` it means you cannot use quora.com in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```css
iframe {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  border:solid 1px #000;
}


#front {
  position:absolute;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  left:120px;
  top:120px;
  background:#f00;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #666;
  
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.link1.com"></iframe>
<div id="front">
<iframe src="https://www.link1.com"></iframe></div>
```

In general, it shouldn’t be a problem to have a DIV placed on top of an iFrame